# SelectedColumns giving error in table component in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

We are building a plugin for Jira Software (Confluence), I am doing the part that changes a table with a MultiSelect component so that only the columns chosen by the user are displayed. However, during testing, the table is not displayed.
In the Console it appears "selectedColumns is not defined"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYrvi.png)

The script it is located at is the one below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as utils from '../../utils';
import { Multiselect } from 'multiselect-react-dropdown';

export default function TblSubmittedTimesheetReport(props) {

    const headers = [
      { id: 0, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.period'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.period'] : 'Period', value: 'period' },
      { id: 1, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.user'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.user'] : 'Employee', value: 'employee' },
      { id: 2, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.team'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.team'] : 'Team', value: 'team' },
      { id: 3, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.approver'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.approver'] : 'Leader', value: 'approver' },
      { id: 4, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.hourstempo'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.hourstempo'] : 'Jira Hours', value: 'hourstempo' },
      { id: 5, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.hoursponto'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.hoursponto'] : 'Check-in Hours', value: 'hoursponto' },
      { id: 6, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.reason'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.reason'] : 'Reason', value: 'reason' },
      { id: 7, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.submitteddatetime'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.submitteddatetime'] : 'Submitted Date and Time', value: 'approvaldatetime' },
    ]

    const [submittedList, setSubmittedList] = useState([]);

    const [selectedColumns, setSelectedColumns] = useState(headers)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setSubmittedList(props.data.submittedTimesheetsList);
    }, [props])

    function onColumnSelect(selectedList) {
      (selectedList && setSelectedColumns(selectedList));
    }

    function hasToShow(columnIdx) {
      selectedColumns.any(({ id }) => id === columnIdx);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="hdrtimesheets-element">
                <label htmlFor="visibleColumns">Visible Columns:</label>
                <Multiselect
                    options={headers}
                    onSelect={onColumnSelect}
                    onRemove={onColumnSelect}
                    displayValue="name"
                    showCheckbox={true}
                />
            </div>
            <table id="tblSubmTimesheetsReport" className="pages-tbl">
                <thead>
                  <h2>{props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.submittedts'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.submittedts'] : 'Pending of Approval Timesheets'}</h2>
                    <tr>
                      {
                        headers.map((item) => {     
                          return hasToShow(item.id) && (
                            <th onClick={() => sortTableSub(item.id)}>{item.name}</th>
                          );
                        })
                      }
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        (submittedList && submittedList.length > 0 && (
                            submittedList.map((item) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr key={item.id}>
                                        { hasToShow(0) && ( <td>{utils.formatPeriodDate(new Date(item.periodStartDateISO + ' 00:00:00'))} - {utils.formatPeriodDate(new Date(item.periodEndDateISO + ' 00:00:00'))}</td> ) }
                                        { hasToShow(1) && ( <td>{item.usuario}</td> ) }
                                        { hasToShow(2) && ( <td>{item.team}</td> ) }
                                        { hasToShow(3) && ( <td>{item.approver}</td> ) }
                                        { hasToShow(4) && ( <td>{Number(item.hoursTempo).toFixed(2)}</td> ) }
                                        { hasToShow(5) && ( <td>{((item.horasPonto == '?') ? item.horasPonto : Number(item.horasPonto).toFixed(2))}</td> ) }
                                        { hasToShow(6) && ( <td>{item.reason}</td> ) }
                                        { hasToShow(7) && ( <td>{item.actionDate}</td> ) }
                                    </tr>
                                );
                            })
                        )) || (
                            (!submittedList || submittedList.length === 0) && (
                                <tr>
                                    <td colSpan={`${(selectedColumns && selectedColumns.length) || 0}`}><h1>{props.texts ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.noshowdata'] : 'No data for this interval'}</h1></td>
                                </tr>
                            ))

                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );

    function sortTableSub(n) {
      console.log("Ordenando: " +n);
      debugger;
        var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
        table = document.getElementById("tblSubmTimesheetsReport");
        switching = true;
        dir = "asc";

        while (switching) {
          switching = false;
          rows = table.rows;

          for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
            shouldSwitch = false;

            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            if (dir == "asc") {
              if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
              }
            } else if (dir == "desc") {
              if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
              }
            }
          }
          if (shouldSwitch) {
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
            switchcount ++;
          } else {
            if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
              dir = "desc";
              switching = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: `selectedColumns.any(…)` what is `.any` did you mean `.some`?